# Update JavaFX application using UpdateFX

Tags: java, javafx, auto-update

I use [UpdateFX](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx) framework for updating my app. So when I start my app, it checks for updates. Here is the snippet which checks for newer version :

```
UpdateFX updater = new UpdateFX(this.getClass());
updater.checkUpdates();
```

I download the file if new version is realised. But how to rewrite it when program is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UpdateFX takes care of it. I would advice you to spend sometime going through the UpdateFX source code. If you do, you will find [InstallerService](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/briksoftware/updatefx/core/InstallerService.java) which actually updates the Application by calling a OS native command using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

For [MAC OS](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/briksoftware/updatefx/core/InstallerService.java#L55), it passes the PID to the [bash script](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/briksoftware/updatefx/util/installdmg.sh#L7) which puts the process on hold till the present application is running :

```
while /bin/ps -p $APP_PID > /dev/null; do 
  /bin/sleep 1; 
done
```

It then **kills** the current running application using [`Platform.exit()`](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/briksoftware/updatefx/core/InstallerService.java#L68). *Since the bash process is independent, it keeps executing*.

Once the application exits, the above condition in the loop defaults to `false` and the script continues the execution by emulating disk images, [removing the old file](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/briksoftware/updatefx/util/installdmg.sh#L18) and [copying the new file](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/briksoftware/updatefx/util/installdmg.sh#L19) into Application directory. It then [opens](https://github.com/bitgamma/updatefx/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/briksoftware/updatefx/util/installdmg.sh#L27) the newly installed Application.